# ¿Cargar Datatables en una tabla cargada dinamicamente con Jquery?

Tags: jquery, datatables

Tengo un tabla en una pagina html que cargo en otro html con jquery `load();`

Al ser cargada dinámicamente el dom no la reconoce y no puedo cargar la tabla.

```
$(function() {
       $('#contenedor-home').load('Views/Vista1.php');//Vista1 contiene la tabla

tabla = $('#example').DataTable( {
        "language": {
            "url": "js/lib/spanis-datatables.json"
        },
        "ajax": {
            "url": "Services/getAllUsuarios.php",
            "dataSrc": ""
        },
        "columns": [
            { "data": "id" },
            { "data": "nombre" },
            { "data": "password" },
            { "data":"id",
                "render": function(data){
                    return '<a class="delete" onclick="eliminarUsuario('+data+')"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o btn-lg"></i></a><a class="edit" onclick="editarUsuario('+data+')"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-pencil btn-lg"></i></a>';
                }}
        ]
    } );
}
```

Comment: Necesitamos mas información, agrega algo de tu código con el qeu haces el load y el dom

Comment: El load carga un html externo en el index.html dentro de un div id='contenedor-home'. Al cargar el index.html le digo que traiga ese contenido donde hay una tabla.¿Como puedo cargar esa tabla con datatables?

Comment: Puede tener q ver con que usas #example y no existe ese div?

Comment: #example si que existe y si pongo la tabla en index.html se carga sin problemas. El problema esta en meterla en una vista que se carga con jquery.

Comment: Fíjate que el load tiene una función que se ejecuta cuando termina puede que sea un tema de asincronismo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Como dice @Cesar moro en los comentarios, posiblemente sea un problema de llamadas asíncronas.

Intenta hacer lo siguiente:

```
$('#contenedor-home').load('Views/Vista1.php', function(){
   // acá pones el código configura tu Datatable
});
```

Esto permite que se ejecute el código de llenado de la tabla justo después que se haya cargado correctamente el HTML de Vista1.php